# MYSql Code to Display data from two tables into Single one

Tags: mysql, database-design

I have two tables States and Cities. 
In teststates table: there are data regarding states of different countries [image]

The code column has id for states associated with it

In Cities table:
      there is region column which has same id as of code column in teststates table.
[image]

Requirement:
I want the Code in mysql to fetch id from the teststates table column and replace it into region column in testcities table as I want only two columns which are city name and region in testcities table. Please help me!

Comment: Do you want a SELECT query, or Update Query.

Comment: I want update query that first fetch the region from teststates table and then update the region column in testcities table.

Comment: How do you want to fetch region from teststates ??

Comment: the code column in teststates refers to region column in testcities table and I want to first read it from states table and update region in test cities table. I want to do it via some code like nesting looping because I have alot of tables and manually it would take lot of time for the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

`select a.name,b.region from teststates a,testcities b where a.country = b.country`

This will return City Name and Region Name columns joining on Country name from both tables.